int64/* type parameter */ does not satisfy constraints.Integer
I am working with a function passing custom types:
type OrderedType[T constraints.Ordered] struct {
    Value T
}

func (o *OrderedType[T]) GetValue() T {
    return o.Value
}

func (o *OrderedType[T]) Compare(other interfaces.Comparable[T]) int {
    if o.Value < other.GetValue() {
        return -1
    } else if o.Value > other.GetValue() {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func NewInt[T constraints.Integer](value T) interfaces.Comparable[T] {
    return &OrderedType[T]{
        Value: value,
    }
}

The Comparable interfaces is defined like below:
type Comparable[T any] interface {
    GetValue() T
    Compare(other Comparable[T]) int
}

Now I am trying to call NewInt like this:
func (io *IO[int64]) WriteInt(values []int64) {
    asSeq := utils.SliceToSeq(values)
    asComparable := utils.Map[int64, interfaces.Comparable[int64]](func (v int64) interfaces.Comparable[int64] {return NewInt(v)}, asSeq)
    io.WriteFromSeq(asComparable)
}

But I couldn't resolve the following error
int64/* type parameter */ does not satisfy constraints.Integer

The constraints module is the one defined here. I have spent over 5 hours trying different things but no luck. I need help.
Edit: I have provided the definition of IO and utils.SliceToSeq below:
type IO[T any] struct{
    ctx context.Context
    canc context.CancelFunc
    key string 
}

I know the type parameter in the above definition is not used currently, but I am planning to use it in the future.
// SliceToSeq converts a slice to a sequence. Defined in utils.go
func SliceToSeq[T any](slice []T) iter.Seq[T] {
    return func(yield func (T) bool){
        for _, v := range slice {
            if !yield(v){
                return
            }
        }
    }
}


Also see the Go FAQ: “Why can’t I use a more specific type for the receiver of a parameterized type?”
